# How do I debug errors with enabling the NFS kernel module?

Tags: 18.04, kernel, nfs, modprobe

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and wanted to use an NFS shared drive.
On most of my servers it just simply worked with 
`sudo modprobe nfs`.

But on this specific server, which was set up exactly the same way (even the same kernel); it returns an error which is the following:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nfs': Key was rejected by service
```

So far I have tried:

- Restarting the server.
- Removing and purging nfs-common and then reinstalling it.

Have no clue how to solve this issue, as it has never occurred to me before.

Thanks!